# How to sync photos to iPod 6g

Tags: itunes, photos, ipod-nano

Today I was trying to get photos onto my iPod. It is a sixth-generation IPod nano, and I was using iTunes 12.4. However, I was not able to sync photos to the iPod. Why is that? Here is what it looks like:

[image]

For some reason, Photos is not appearing below the name of the iPod.
So: how do I sync photos onto a 6g iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong section.
Photos & their sync options are in the main Summary section for that specific device

[image]

Click the Device icon in the header bar to get there - you get a drop menu if you have more than one device, otherwise it just switches...

[image]